# Putting the results of a first JSON file of to subparts of a second one when key matches

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have a geojson file with results for each province and one that gives other results for each constituency (an administrative part of the province). I would like to make a third one that puts the results of the first one for each 'constituency' level of the second one that has the same `province` with the first one, so I did the following code. It works but it's not optimized at all for the actual file which is far bigger, and which I can share with you if you think it can help me optimize the code.

```
import json
import pandas as pd


def find_segment(province_queried):
    with open('research.geojson', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        dct_research = json.load(f)
        for feature in dct_research['features']:
            for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
                province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name")
                segments = feature.get("properties", {}).get("segments")
                if province == province_queried:
                    return segments

def main():
    with open('maroc-swing.json') as f:
        dct_constituencies = json.load(f)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    d = []
    for feature in dct_constituencies['features']:
        for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
            province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_1")
            constituency = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_4", {})
            segments = find_segment(province)
            d.append({"Party Affiliation": key,
                      "Province": province,
                      "Constituency Name": constituency,
                      "segments": segments})

    column_names = ["Province", "Constituency Name", "Party Affiliation", "segments"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=column_names)

    df.to_csv("constituencies_with_segments.csv")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you prefer it with drawings I'm basically transformint the right hand file:

[image]

Into:

[image]

It means that all the constituents of the same province will have the same results that come from 'research.json'. Right now I'm trying to do it in the key name_2.

Here it is `constituences.json`:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "totalFeatures": 1515,
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.1",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.27163887,
                33.24041367
              ],
              [
                -7.27286911,
                33.24623871
              ],
              [
                -7.26732922,
                33.25904083
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 1,
        "name_4": "Ahlaf",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.27286911,
          33.22112656,
          -6.93353081,
          33.38970184
        ],
        "swing_count": 1,
        "polling_station_count": 15,
        "turnout": 0.4780299144225693,
        "results": {
          "PI": 187,
          "PJD": 88,
          "PAM": 59,
          "USFP": 1530,
          "APFGD": 2,
          "PPS": 15,
          "RNI": 708,
          "MP": 56,
          "UC": 3,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 8,
          "PEDD": 0,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 0,
          "USAPMD": 10
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 5953,
          "nbre_votants": 2997,
          "nbre_nuls": 328,
          "nbre_exprimees": 2669
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.06666666666666667
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "fd597jf1799.2",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.00001287,
                33.63414383
              ],
              [
                -7.00081205,
                33.6269989
              ],
              [
                -6.99825382,
                33.60465622
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "geometry_name": "geom",
      "properties": {
        "id_0": 152,
        "iso": "MAR",
        "name_0": "Morocco",
        "id_1": 1,
        "name_1": "Chaouia - Ouardigha",
        "id_2": 1,
        "name_2": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_3": 1,
        "name_3": "Ben Slimane",
        "id_4": 2,
        "name_4": "Ain Tizgha",
        "varname_4": null,
        "ccn_4": 0,
        "cca_4": null,
        "type_4": "Commune Rural",
        "engtype_4": "Rural Commune",
        "bbox": [
          -7.12737417,
          33.57954407,
          -6.99144888,
          33.78071213
        ],
        "swing_count": 11,
        "polling_station_count": 23,
        "turnout": 0.3912592182242994,
        "results": {
          "PI": 1837,
          "PJD": 366,
          "PAM": 143,
          "USFP": 22,
          "APFGD": 44,
          "PPS": 773,
          "RNI": 109,
          "MP": 111,
          "UC": 9,
          "FFD": 0,
          "MDS": 0,
          "AAR": 0,
          "P Neo-Democrates": 76,
          "PEDD": 27,
          "PRD": 2,
          "PRV": 0,
          "PDI": 0,
          "PGVM": 0,
          "PALAMAL": 0,
          "PCS": 0,
          "PUD": 0,
          "PDN": 1,
          "PLJS": 0,
          "PSD": 0,
          "P Annahda": 0,
          "PA": 0,
          "UMD": 2,
          "USAPMD": 514
        },
        "voter_file": {
          "nbre_sieges": 3,
          "nbre_inscrits": 8262,
          "nbre_votants": 4479,
          "nbre_nuls": 443,
          "nbre_exprimees": 4036
        },
        "swing_ratio": 0.4782608695652174
      }
    }
  ],
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
    }
  },
  "bbox": [
    -13.2287693,
    27.62881088,
    -0.93655348,
    35.96390533
  ]
}
```

And here's 'research.json':

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81124878
              ],
              [
                -7.18458319,
                33.81097412
              ],
              [
                -7.18319511,
                33.81097412
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.1",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Ben Slimane",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 24,
            "intention_rate": 20.83
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 10,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 12,
            "intention_rate": 8.33
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 4,
            "intention_rate": 75
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 44.44
          },
          "RNI": {
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 100
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 2,
            "intention_rate": 50
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 55
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -6.3649292,
                33.22292328
              ],
              [
                -6.38369083,
                33.21116257
              ],
              [
                -6.39487886,
                33.19342422
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.2",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Khouribga",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 46,
            "No": 12,
            "Yes": 13,
            "total": 71,
            "intention_rate": 18.31
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 79,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 84,
            "intention_rate": 1.19
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 14,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 4,
            "total": 19,
            "intention_rate": 21.05
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 12,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 7,
            "total": 20,
            "intention_rate": 35
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 2,
            "total": 8,
            "intention_rate": 25
          },
          "RNI": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "Yes": 3,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 50
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 5,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 214
      }
    },
    {
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                -3.77662611,
                34.86683655
              ],
              [
                -3.7705431,
                34.86468506
              ],
              [
                -3.75482011,
                34.86924362
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "md898kw3185.57",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Taza",
        "type": "Province",
        "segments": {
          "UND": {
            "I don't know yet": 16,
            "No": 28,
            "Yes": 14,
            "total": 58,
            "intention_rate": 24.14
          },
          "ABS": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 29,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 32,
            "intention_rate": 3.12
          },
          "PJD": {
            "I don't know yet": 9,
            "No": 4,
            "Yes": 23,
            "total": 36,
            "intention_rate": 63.89
          },
          "PAM": {
            "I don't know yet": 4,
            "No": 1,
            "Yes": 1,
            "total": 6,
            "intention_rate": 16.67
          },
          "OTH": {
            "I don't know yet": 3,
            "No": 3,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 11,
            "intention_rate": 45.45
          },
          "RNI": {
            "total": 0,
            "intention_rate": 0
          },
          "IST": {
            "I don't know yet": 2,
            "No": 2,
            "Yes": 5,
            "total": 9,
            "intention_rate": 55.56
          }
        },
        "sample_size": 152
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Sadly my attempt takes too much time. Do you know how I can optimize it, or do you have a better idea in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_segment` loads the json file every time it is called. It would be much faster to load the data once and return a dict mapping province to segments.  Also, `key` doesn't appear to be used, so remove that for-loop

```
def load_research(filename='research.geojson'):
    """loads json data from filename and return a dict of segments
       keyed by province."""

    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        dct_research = json.load(f)

    data = {}

    for feature in dct_research['features']:
        province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name")
        segments = feature.get("properties", {}).get("segments")
        data[province] = segments

    return data
```

In `main()` it looks like `province`, `constituency`, and `segments` only depend on `feature` and not on `key`.  So calculate them before the `for key ...` loop.  That should speed things up a lot.

```
def main():
    # load data into a dict keyed by province
    research = load_research()

    with open('maroc-swing.json') as f:
        dct_constituencies = json.load(f)

    d = []
    for feature in dct_constituencies['features']:

        province = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_1", "")
        constituency = feature.get("properties", {}).get("name_4", "")

        # this is now a dict lookup rather than loading a json file
        segments = research[province]

        for key in feature.get("properties", {}).get("results", {}):
            d.append({"Party Affiliation": key,
                      "Province": province,
                      "Constituency Name": constituency,
                      "segments": segments})

    column_names = ["Province", "Constituency Name", "Party Affiliation", "segments"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=column_names)

    df.to_csv("constituencies_with_segments.csv")
```

NB. I haven't tested the code, so there may be some typos etc.